# Does chkdsk without volume letter check current volume or everything?

Tags: windows, chkdsk

`chkdsk /r`

Does it check current volume or does it check every volume (full drive)?

I read somewhere that without letter it works on current volume (so c: if I run it from c:/) so I decided to be fancy and run it like this for checking c: (I have disk problem and previously chkdsk fixed them). But now it is running for far too long, recently I run it on c: it was for 1-2 hours and now it is >5 hours. Not sure is it checking everything or is my disk having problems.

Can't google it out because of "how to run chkdsk on volume without letter".

Comment: Hint for future searches. Even though it's not a unix tool, searching "man (toolname)" will usually get you the full instruction set for usage. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk

Comment: I believe it runs in the context of the current drive. Beware though that the `r` option takes a lot longer than `f` so you may be looking at the consequence of the option flag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chkdsk is *volume* specific, as it it works with file systems.  It is unaware of the physical or virtual disk(s)  that the specified volume occupies.

You are correct, when running chkdsk without a volume parameter, it uses the current volume.  Microsoft's [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk) does not mention this, but this is definitely the case.

Comment: I run it all the time without volume parameter, it will check the currently booted volume.

Comment: @Moab Currently _booted_ volume? I think you mean the current volume. I'm currently on a laptop with a single drive so can't verify it, but I'm pretty sure if you do `cd D: & chkdsk` it will check the D: drive, not the C: drive that you booted from.

Comment: I do have several volumes and I can confirm that without parameters it uses the current volume.